# Asp.net postback controls (radio button) not working in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have asp radio button inside the div. But when I get the value in the server side, the updated values are not reflecting.

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    title: "cancel dialog",
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto'
}).dialog('open');


<div id="divDialog">
<asp:RadioButton Text="All Members" ID="rdbAllMembers" runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="members" />
<asp:RadioButton Text="This Member Only" ID="rdbThisMember" runat="server" GroupName="members" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Asp.net controls should be inside the form tag. But when you use the jquery dialog, the div is added outside the form tag. So the control values will be updated properly. Only default values will be available always. So in order for that, add the add to the form tag.

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    title: "cancel dialog",
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    open: function (type, data) {
        **$(this).parent().appendTo("form");**
    }
});
```